# Optional String vs Empty

Tags: objective-c, swift, string, null, option-type

### String? vs ""

Why does Apple use [optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string) in many cases (but not everywhere)? For example, if you have a [`UILabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel), you can clear it with two ways:

```
label.text = ""
label.text = nil
```

because `text` property is an `Optional<String>`.

Why do they do this? Is it just for compatibility with Objective-C, or there are any other practical reasons? Is storing `nil` is more memory-efficient then storing `""`? Will `String?` perform slightly better then `String?`?

Suppose I need to create a structure or class with text property, that can be empty. Should it be optional?

Comment: Semantically, empty is not the same as nil. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9vg8.jpg ;)

Answer (score 1):

When an object (in this case the text field) is `nil`, it does not exist and does not use any memory. An empty String object `""` on the other hand uses up memory and takes more time to check.

Whether to use optionals or not highly depends on your task. You should read more about pointers and optionals in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Comment: Do you know how strings are stored in Swift?

Comment: Note that the textfield text property default value is an empty string. Even if you assign nil to it and check if it is nil it will return false

Answer (score 1):

You are using a memory location when u put a string to "" it has a reference in memory , but on the other side if you put a string to nil it will deallocate its reference in memory and release that location.